# (APL) About the power and circle functions

Tags: complex-numbers, pi, apl, dyalog, eulers-number

Why does `*○0j1` outputs -1 but `*(○0j1)` doesn’t? (`¯1j1e¯16`)
What is the difference between them?

Expected `*(○0j1)` to output the same thing as `*○0j1`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming this is Dyalog APL, then it's because `*○0j1` is recognised as an idiom and the exact expected result is returned rather than being calculated as `*(○0j1)` is.

Dyalog's idiom list is [here](http://docs.dyalog.com/18.2/CheatSheet%20-%20Idioms.pdf)